# Issue building project on Android Studio - support-v4

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm having trouble running and building apk's on my Android studio Project, I'm searching and searching but can't find any suitable solution for my problem.

Gradle console stacktrace:

```
trouble writing output: D:\android-sdk-windows\Shairlook-Def-git\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-22.0.0-f0c61aa475a654ffa9a9c544ec7d938bf31cfae2.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)

FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
D:\android-sdk-windows\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --output    D:\android-sdk-windows\Shairlook-Def-git\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-22.0.0-f0c61aa475a654ffa9a9c544ec7d938bf31cfae2.jar D:\android-sdk-windows\Shairlook-Def-git\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\22.0.0\libs\internal_impl-22.0.0.jar
Error Code:
3
Output:
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.
El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.

trouble writing output: D:\android-sdk-windows\Shairlook-Def-git\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\internal_impl-22.0.0-f0c61aa475a654ffa9a9c544ec7d938bf31cfae2.jar (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada)


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.202 secs
```

This my module `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.shairlook"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'eu.ocathain.com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
}
```

Any idea about what it can be?

I just can't figure it out, anybody can shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alrighty

the solution was to update gradle on `build.gradle` of my project, not module

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

it was set to `0.9.0` previously, thank you.